# Python error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory(read_csv with open)

Tags: python

```
with open('~/Documents/data.csv', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())

data=pd.read_csv('~/Documents/data.csv')
```

when I used the first `"with open"` method, I got an error. But there is no problem when I use the `"read_csv"`.

So could anyone tell me why?
Thank you!

Comment: Not all functions process the `~` in a path. Some just take it as a tilde.

Comment: What is the error `with open` gave?

Comment: The error is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: Try using the full path eg `/home/<username>/Documents/data.csv` or use a module like `pathlib` to [`expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser).

Comment: I have just modified the "~" to the full path, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With `open()`, you have to use the `os.path.expanduser()` function to expand the tilde `~` into the actual home directory of the user:

```
import os
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/data.csv'), 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Pandas' `read_csv()` does that for you.

(A word of warning: since `~` is a valid character in Linux filenames, just replacing `~` with `os.getenv("HOME")` is a very bad idea...)